# Drawing a diagram of a data structure (`std::vector` from C++)

Tags: data-structures

I'm looking for a way to show data structures in my slides (Beamer).  My first task is to show something that looks like a C++ vector.

Something like this:

[image]

Note that the final arrow points "one past" the end.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you are using Beamer, TikZ seems the right tool for the job (there are others, but TikZ is automatically loaded by Beamer). It's easy to draw arrows, create nodes with text, draw rectangles, and colour them.

Comment: @Manuel I don't think that's true. It loads `pgf` but not `tikz`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started....

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,fill=LightSteelBlue!60,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm] (a) at (2,0) {capacity};
\node[draw,fill=LightSteelBlue!60,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm] (b) at (2,1) {end};
\node[draw,rectangle, fill=LightSteelBlue!60,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm] (c) at (2,2) {begin};
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3}
 \node[draw,rectangle, fill=LightSteelBlue!60,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm]  (d\x) at (10,\x-2){};
\foreach \x in {0,...,4}
\node[draw,rectangle, fill=White,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm]  (e\x) at (10,\x-7){};
\node[minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm] (f) at (10,-8){};
\draw[->,very thick] (c.east)--(d3.west);
\draw[->,very thick] (b.east)--(e4.west);
\draw[->,very thick] (a.east)--(f.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```